# To to disable "Show comment window after each session" in Teamviewer

Tags: teamviewer

Since Teamviewer 12 I constantly get this dialag after each session that asks me for notes. I really don't need it. So I found a setting where I can disable this. But the setting is disabled! Any idea what I'm missing?

[image]

**Update:**
I've tried @Ryan Tse suggestion, but even in the admin interface it's the same. And I'm the account owner..

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the TeamViewer documentation, this is an administrative option that is controlled by your company. If you wish to change this, you need to login to the administrative panel (https://login.teamviewer.com/LogOn) for TeamViewer and edit your user there to set that option.

Comment: Seems like the issue went away. Maybe it was a bug that this was greyed out.